# In FP how do you set a reciprocal relationship?

Tags: javascript, clojure, functional-programming

In FP where there is no mutable state and every operation returns a new state of the world.  Given: I have a contact list and an individual contact.

I add Dirk to my address book.  Dirk is a child of my address book.  My address book is the parent of Dirk.  Being that I can't set both references at the same time I have a dilemma.  The parent-child relationship should define an infinite cycle where I can step from parent to child to parent to same child forever.

Using JavaScript syntax:

```
var addresses = new AddressBook();
var dirk = new Contact(addresses, 'Dirk', ...);
```

On the second line I am passing in the address book without Dirk.  Dirk has a parent reference to an address book without him in it.

I suspect the answer but I want to be sure.  Am I actually going to mutate state to set this up properly or is there some technique I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this kind of thing to work the way that it would in your JavaScript example (so you could directly look up the actual address book in the actual children), you have to make the address book mutable. It's not even because of the initial creation of the parent and child (that can be managed, in some functional languages more easily than in others), but because if you then go on to add further references to the address book, the old entries will still hold their outdated versions of the address book.

In Clojure, it's tempting to use an Atom or Ref to hold the entire address book in such a case and then also put an Atom or Ref pointing to the address book in each child, but Clojure reference types are only really designed to hold immutable data and nesting them may lead to problems.

A better solution is to give symbolic names to your entities (keywords, numbers, UUIDs are all fine) and store them in a map somewhere. Using a single atom could look like this:

```
(def state (atom {:contacts {:dirk ...}
                  :address-books {}}))
```

Then you can add Dirk to a new address book (creating it along the way in the form of a hash map) like so:

```
(swap! state (fn [state-map]
               (update-in state-map [:address-book :my-address-book]
                 (fn [abook]
                   (let [entries (get abook :entries [])]
                     (assoc abook :entries (conj entries :dirk)))))))
```

Note that this adds Dirk to the address book in the form of a symbolic reference (`:dirk`) to be looked up in the top-level state map under the `:contacts` key. If you also want the Dirk contact to maintain a list of address books of which it is a member, use a further `update-in` adding the appropriate information to the Dirk contact, possibly removing some nesting with `->`:

```
(-> state-map
    (update-in [...] ...)
    (update-in [...] ...))
```

Comment: It did occur to me on the drive home from the cafe that using pointers (as you suggested) might have something to do with it.

Comment: Isn't that whole complicated/long `update-in/swap/fn/fn` thing just a complicated way of writing `(swap! state update-in [:address-book :my-address-book :entries] (fnil conj []) :dirk)`?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with and without mutable state with the same idea. You run a function that takes the original state of the addresses, and the state you would like to add, which then returns a new set of addresses including the new state. It does this without destroying the original of course, because someone could be looking at it.

define the base address book:

```
user> (def addresses [])                         
#'user/addresses
```

define a new address book containing the new value:

```
user> (def book-with-dirk 
        (conj addresses {:name "dirk" :address "123 internet st."}))
#'user/book-with-dirk
user> book-with-dirk
[{:name "dirk", :address "123 internet st."}]
```

which does not change the base address book, rather it creates a new address book that efficiently combines the original address book with the new value for dirk. So addresses is still the same.

```
user> addresses    
[]
```

You can also **use a managed mutable state** to maintain the contents of the identity named addresses in a functional manner. **the original value in the address atom still exists if anyone is looking at it** (and is GCd otherwise)

```
user> (def addresses (atom []))      
#'user/addresses
```

make a new address book that just as above includes dirk, except this one also creates the next value in the identity of addresses:

```
user> (def book-with-dirk (swap! addresses conj {:name "dirk" :address "123 internet st."}))
#'user/book-with-dirk
```

now book-with-dirk is a value containing the book with dirk in it.

```
user> book-with-dirk                                       
[{:name "dirk", :address "123 internet st."}]
```

and addresses contains the new value as well.

```
user> @addresses
[{:name "dirk", :address "123 internet st."}]
```

If I then add Joe, book-with-dirk will not change

```
user> (swap! addresses conj {:name "Joe" :address "321 internet st."})
[{:name "dirk", :address "123 internet st."} 
 {:name "Joe", :address "321 internet st."}]

user> book-with-dirk
[{:name "dirk", :address "123 internet st."}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I can read Schema a little better than Clojure, but I figured the good answers would probably come from the Clojure community.  Thanks for chiming in. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned FP in general, I'd add one additional view - **lazy evaluation**. I'm neither good in JS nor Clojure, so I'll give examples in different languages, but perhaps it'd be possible to use the idea as well.

Many functional languages have the concept of [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). This means that a value is computed only at the point it is actually needed. Naturally, such lazy computation must be referentially transparent (must not depend on outside information, must be free of mutable state and side effects etc.), because we never know when (or if at all) they'll be evaluated.

For example, in Haskell all computations are lazy, so we can write just

```
let address = Address contact {- other fields -}
    contact = Contact address {- other fields -}
 in {- some expression that uses address and contact -}
```

Or we can make a list whose tail is the list itself. The result is an infinite list with a repeated element that takes just a constant amount of memory

```
infList :: a -> [a]
infList x = l
  where l = x : l
```

For more information, see [Tying the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_knot) on Haskell Wiki.

If a language lacks lazy evaluation, you can implement it yourself: If a value hasn't been requested yet, compute it, store it and return it. Next time, just return what has been computed before. Of course you'll need mutability for it, but the mutable state is hidden inside the software component, and if the computation is referentially transparent, the mutability will never leak out.